# Redirect missing pagination to base page

Tags: wp-redirect

I have a strange problem with wp_redirect that I can't seem to solve myself.

I'm trying to redirect previously existing pages back to the root of the page so:

http://example.com/slug/page/5/?sort=no-image would redirect back to http://example.com/slug/?sort=no-image in case the page number doesn't exist anymore.

I hooked into template_redirect with the bellow function but for some reason I end up in a redirect loop. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Forgot to mention that the URL ending in the redirect loop also has a query string appended.

```
function filter_redirect() {
global $wp_query, $wp;
$requested_url = add_query_arg( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '', trailingslashit(home_url( $wp->request )) );
$redirect_url = preg_replace('#/page/[0-9]+?(/+)?$#', '/', $requested_url);
$current_page = (get_query_var('paged'));
if ($current_page > $wp_query->max_num_pages) {
wp_redirect($redirect_url,301);
exit();
}
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'filter_redirect' );
```

Comment: Had you tried dumping all of it and seeing if conditions and URLs are what you expect them to be?

Comment: Yes, the url prints the same as in the browser and the condition is met as long as the current page number is greater than the max_num_pages. This is a follow up on question 160381  .

Answer (score -1):

Changing the regex to

```
/\/page\/([0-9]+)?(\/+)?/
```

worked for me